# How to use a Dust.JS variable in a @uses parameter

Tags: variables, parameter-passing, dust.js

I am trying to place a variable in the parameter of a @uses path, like so...

```
{@uses parameter="/p/a/t/h/{variable}/e/t/c"}
   ...
{/uses}
```

Here is a more pragmatic example...

```
{@uses parameter="/api/{user}/profile"}
   ...
{/uses}
```

Needless to say, its not working.  So, what is the correct way to approach this?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Is it a custom helper?

Comment: I was more specifically asking how to pass a dynamic string (aka: "it has a variable in it") as a parameter.

Comment: P.S.  I eventually abandoned Dust and replaced it with Angular (http://angularjs.org/).  I'm much happier now!